# Other proof for perimeter of a circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, alternative-proof

Almost everyone knows the most basic formula for the perimeter of a circle $2\pi r$. I can prove it as follows, but my question is about a simpler idea to show the proof to the students who do not know limit process.
I usually start with a regular n-polygon inscribed in a circle. With respect to the picture we can say $$\text{Perimeter}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \ n \cdot s(n)=l$$ so
$$l= \lim_{n \to \infty} \ n \cdot s(n)=\\  \lim_{n \to \infty} \ n \cdot r\sqrt{2(1-\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n}))}=\\
\sqrt 2 r\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt{\frac{n^2\sin^2(\frac{2\pi}{n})}{(1+\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n}))}}=\\
\sqrt 2 r\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2}{2}}=\\2\pi r$$
[image]

Is there another idea to show the proof?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You seem to be looking for a way of determining a value of $\pi$ without limits. 
 Unfortunately, computing the area or circumference of a circle fundamentally requires some kind of limiting process. On the plus side, Archimedes figured out how to do it *long* before the modern notion of a limit, so I think that it is likely that you can explain the *idea* of a limit and get a good, solid understanding of the result without resorting to the formality.

Comment: Actually, the $\pi$ is BY DEFINITION, the ratio between the perimeter and the diameter of a circle, from which it follows immediately that $\text{perimeter} = 2\pi r$. What you actually have to prove in order to such definition to be correct is that the ratio is the same for all the circles.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I believe you're thinking in the formula for the *area*.

Comment: @jjagmath Not to be overly pedantic, but one definition of $\pi$ is that it is the ratio of perimeter and diameter (or, perhaps, the **length** of the perimeter of the unit circle).  It can also be defined to be the **area** of a circle with radius $1$, or $\arccos(-1)$ (where $\arccos$ can be defined in terms of a Taylor series expansion or in relation to a particular set of differential equation, or whatever).

Comment: @jjagmath No, I am *not* "thinking in the formula for the *area*".  If you want to determine a *value* for $\pi$, which appears to be related to what the asker is asking, some kind of limiting process is required.  And you have to say what you mean by "$\pi$" (again, many definitions, which all happen to agree).

Comment: @XanderHenderson I was talking about your reference to Archimedes, who actually defined $\pi$ as the ratio of perimeter and diameter and then proved the formula for the area.

Comment: In your derivation, you have $\cos 2\pi/n$.  You are assuming that the circumference of a unit circle is $2\pi$.  You are assuming your conclusion.